# Как выводить сообщение об успешной отправке формы?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно чтобы в случае отправки формы, в label или span отображалось сообщение. Как это реализовать?

```
<form name="form-1">
  <input name="name" required placeholder="Ваше имя *" value="" class="form-control" type="text">
  <input name="tell" required placeholder="Ваш телефон *" value="" class="form-control" type="text">
  <input name="send" class="btnform feedback" type="submit" value="Оформить заявку">
</form>
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос, покажите пример кода...

Comment: код писать не буду. напишу на пальцах, как я понимаю. человек форму заполняет, нажимает "отправить". эта кнопка - объект DOM

Comment: Поправил код. За основу взял скрипт http://postovoy.net/22.html

Comment: код писать не буду. напишу на пальцах, как я понимаю. человек форму заполняет, нажимает "отправить". эта кнопка - объект DOM. к объекту можно код привязать, запихнутый в функцию - обработчик. в этом коде пишем джаваскриптом шаблон. "берем" value (это то, ЧТО ввел человек в форму "ручками") у объекта формы, сравниваем с шаблоном с помощью джаваскрипта. если все правильно, то после сравнения запускаем функцию формы - submit() и форма поехала на сервер. после этого "беру" (например, по айди) нужный мне объект (спан)для отображения сообщения "сообщение отправлено" и запихиваю в него текстовый узел

Comment: полетел запрос на сервер, AJAX - если сервер вернул ошибку пишем ошибку, если нет - отображаем сообщение. Если не AJAX - выводим результат на странице...

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="form-1">
  <input name="name" type="tel" pattern="[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]{3}" required placeholder="Ваше имя *" value="" class="form-control" type="text">
  <input name="tell" required placeholder="Ваш телефон *" value="" class="form-control" pattern="[0-9]{5,10}" type="tel">
  <input name="send" class="btnform feedback" type="submit" value="Оформить заявку">
</form>
```

Валидация HTML5 но лучше проверять данные еще и на сервере, и возвращать результат JSON. А форму слать AJAX и в зависимости от ответа сервера либо показывать ошибки либо сообщение о том что запрос принят